# PowerShell Advanced functions are difficult to properly pipe

Tags: function, powershell

I can't get my head around the piping thing. I've read through the `Get-Help` and in Jon Dones his examples but I can't understand it properly. So I started playing with a function I found online to execute a script block in a specific culture (regional settings).

I managed to have it process these arguments correctly:

```
Use-Culture de-DE {Get-Date}, {Get-TimeStamp}
Use-Culture nl-BE {Get-Date}, {Get-TimeStamp}
```

But when I try to pipe to `Use-Culture`, it's just not working at all:

```
de-DE {Get-Date}, {Get-TimeStamp} | Use-Culture
nl-BE {Get-Date} | Use-Culture
```

I feel like I'm missing the basic concept here. There was another question on StackOverlfow talking about this topic. One guy said to use `Foreach`and someone else said to work with `-Inputobject`. Then again, Don Jones used in his Advanced Function no such thing and stated that the `Process` block gets iterated for each object.

What is best practice to pipe multiple arguments to a function? In this case, multiple `Script blocks` to execute against the same `Culture`.

Thank you for your help as always.

```
Function Use-Culture { 
    param( 
            [Parameter(
            Mandatory=$true,Position=0,
            ValueFromPipeline=$true,
            ValueFromPipelineByPropertyName=$true)] 
            [System.Globalization.CultureInfo]$culture, 
            [Parameter(
            Mandatory=$true,Position=1,
            ValueFromPipeline=$true,
            ValueFromPipelineByPropertyName=$true)]  
            [ScriptBlock[]]$code 
    )
    process { 
            ForEach ($_ in $code) {
             trap { 
                   [System.Threading.Thread]::CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = $currentCulture 
             } 
             $currentCulture = [System.Threading.Thread]::CurrentThread.CurrentCulture 
             [System.Threading.Thread]::CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = $culture 
             Invoke-Command $_ 
             [System.Threading.Thread]::CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = $currentCulture 
             }
    }
}
```

Comment: I started an answer for this, and it grew too large. Then I realized no one can explain it better than the manual: `get-help about_Pipelines`. The question you should be asking yourself is "Am I getting any functionality from trying to pipe these parameters to this cmdlet, or am I just scrambling around the syntax and hoping for the best?"

Comment: In this specific case it might not be so useful to pipe script blocks to this command. But I was just trying to figure out how to set the parameters and if the loop needed to be used if multiple arguments needed to be piped. And you're right, the Get-Help in PowerShell is absolutely fantastic. But sometimes best practices or nice to hear/read from people with experience.